# drools coercion fail somethings

Tags: drools

According to the documentation,"Coercion is always in favor of the field type and not the value type"

I tried and it's not always true.

the rule:

```
rule "get event field "
when
    m : Message( getEventField("bigDecimalB") > "7.5" )
then
    System.out.println( "hit" );

end
```

the Message class:

```
public  class Message {

    private Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    public Object getEventField(String key) {
        Object object = map.get(key);
        if (object != null) {
            //class=java.math.BigDecimal in my test
            System.out.println("getEventField, fieldName=" + key + ", class=" + object.getClass().getCanonicalName());
        }
        return object;
}

//setter and getter
}
```

and the test:

```
        String str = "{\"bigDecimalB\":10.2}";
        Map<String, Object> map = JSON.parseObject(str);

        Message message = new Message();
        message.setMap(map);
        kSession.insert(message);
        kSession.fireAllRules();
```

In most cases, it is "bigDecimal comparation" and obviously 10.2 > 7.5, so it prints 'hit'.

But it can fail sometimes and does not print 'hit'.

I thinks it's because the coercion is not sucess and it is "String comparation".It's hard to reproduce. I'm totally confused and don't know why.

I'm using drools-6.2.0-final and alibaba's fastjson(https://github.com/alibaba/fastjson).

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a method declaration like this:

```
 public Object getFooField(String key)
```

what would you think that a stupid computer program might think about the return type of that method?

Comment: would drools know the exact type in runtime ?

Comment: Yes, but that's too late - what you have in mind would require a dynamic decision between many possibilities.